# Rewrite Very Long URL with Lots of Parameters

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the following long URL in htaccess but keeps redirecting to error page

Existing URL:

```
https://www.exampledomain.com/stuff-for-sale?location_value=California%2C+USA&property_status=&adm_lvl_1_sn=CA&country_sn=US&location_type=administrative_area_level_1&stateSearch=CA&swlat=32.528832&nelat=42.0095169&swlng=-124.48200300000002&nelng=-114.13121100000001&lat=36.778261&lng=-119.41793239999998&faddress=California%2C+USA&place_id=ChIJPV4oX_65j4ARVW8IJ6IJUYs
```

I'd like to rewrite simply as:

```
https://www.exampledomain.com/california-stuff-for-sale
```

Is this possible? I know that with this approach I would have to do 50 rewrites for each state but the system requires all the parameters to create a proper search.

This is what I tried so far with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^/stuff-for-sale?q=&location_value=California%2C+USA&adm_lvl_1_sn=CA&country_sn=US&location_type=administrative_area_level_1&stateSearch=CA&swlat=32.528832&nelat=42.0095169&swlng=-124.48200300000002&nelng=-114.13121100000001&lat=36.778261&lng=-119.41793239999998&faddress=California%2C+USA&place_id=ChIJPV4oX_65j4ARVW8IJ6IJUYs /california-stuff-for-sale[L]
```